# How do I remove the longest prefix that appears in an array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, algorithm

I have two arrays, `search` and `target`. I want to find the longest sequence of elements of `search` that starts from the beginning of `search` and which also appears in the same consecutive order in `target`. Then I want to return a copy of `target` with those elements removed.

Here are some examples:

```
search = [4, "apple", 6, "turnip"]
target = [5, "apple", 4, "orange"]
=> [5, "apple", "orange"]           # Delete [4], the longest matching
                                    # prefix of `search`.

search = [4, "apple", 6, "turnip"]
target = [5, "apple", 4, "apple"]
=> [5, "apple"]                     # Delete [4, "apple"], the longest matching
                                    # prefix of `search`.

search = [4, "apple", 6, "turnip"]
target = [5, "apple", 6, 7]
=> [5, "apple", 6, 7]               # Nothing was matched; don't delete anything.
```

What's the most concise way to perform this check?

Answer (score 1):

The solution by Nikita is a good one if you want simple solution that runs in O(m.n) where m and n are lengths of target and search strings.

You can do this in linear time with a bit complex implementation if you need it.
Your problem is very much like a general string search problem. Most efficient string search algorithms work backwards so they are good at finding suffixes (if not exact match). Since you want prefix, you would need to first reverse your search and target strings. Then either run [Boyer-Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) or [KMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) string search. Usual implementations of these algorithms would just give you exact matches. But with slight modification, you can remember the longest prefix match as well. When you are done, you can go back and delete it in another linear pass.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to work out a full solution, but I'd say there are two approaches:

1. Use a pair of external iterators to
   run over the arrays in parallel. 
   There are tutorials on parallel
   iteration around on the internet, or
   check out a copy of The Ruby
   Programming Language which has a
   good description
2. Alternatively you could loop over
   the search array, popping items off
   the target array, until either the
   target array is empty (in which case
   whereever you got to in the search
   is your prefix), or you get to the
   end of the search array (in which
   case it is entirely contained in the
   target array).

There's a nice recipe for parallel iteration at http://flylib.com/books/en/2.44.1.124/1/

Answer (score 0):

Well, this looks simple and compact enough and doesn't compromise complexity

```
s_index = 0
result = target.select do |t|
  match = search[s_index] == t
  s_index += 1 if match
  !match
end
```

[Array#select docs](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#M000429)

Improvements are welcome!
Also, if your `search` array can contain `nil` values, you'll need a border check here (`s_index < search.length`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the code below. But it definitely not tuned for performance.

```
class Array
  def remove(start, length)
    length.times {delete_at start}
    self
  end
end

def remove(a,b)
  b.length.downto(1) do |len|
    index = a.each_cons(len).to_a.index b[0,len]
    return a.remove(index, len) if index
  end
  return a
end

search = [4, "apple", 6, "turnip"]
target = [5, "apple", 4, "orange"]
remove target, search
```